# How to call a graphql registered resolver from another one - Strapi

Tags: node.js, graphql, strapi

I want to extend the graphql resolver of `removeFile` mutation (which comes from the `upload` core plugin).

I have successfully [replaced the resolver](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/v4/code/backend/graphql.html#replacing-resolvers) using the following code on my plugin's `register.js` file, but I haven't yet find a way to call the original resolver of `removeFile` inside my custom one

```js
export default ({ strapi }) => {
  const extensionService = strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension");

  extensionService.use(({ nexus }) => ({
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        removeFile: async (obj, args) => {
          // my custom logic will goes here
          

          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // I WANT TO CALL the original resolver of "removeFile" here
          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


          // other logic will also goes here
        },
      },
    },
  }));
};
```

**So my question is:** How can I call a graphql registered resolver (the original resolver of `removeFile` mutation) from another one (the new registered resolver)?

---

Additional Info: note that I have successfully replaced a controller handler by assign a new function to it and call the old one in some point of time. here is the code

```js
export default ({ strapi }) => {
  strapi.container
    .get("controllers")
    .extend("plugin::upload.admin-file", (controller) => {
      const originalHandler = controller["destroy"].bind(controller);

      controller["destroy"] = async function (ctx) {
        // my custom logic will goes here

        await originalHandler();

        // other logic will also goes here
      };

      return controller;
    });
};
```

Comment: Any update on this? Im looking for the same functionality tight now.

Answer (score 0):

When you override a resolver in Strapi with Graphql, if you want to keep the original implementation on top, you need to call the Strapi inner implementation using (assuming it is called `plugin::upload.admin-file` in your services, you can run `yarn strapi services:list` if you want to see the name of all your services):

```
const { toEntityResponse } = strapi.service("plugin::graphql.format").returnTypes;
const response = await strapi.services["plugin::upload.adminfile"].remove(args);
return toEntityResponse(response);
```

So in your case the code would be

```
export default ({ strapi }) => {
  const extensionService = strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension");

  extensionService.use(({ nexus }) => ({
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        removeFile: async (obj, args) => {
          // my custom logic will goes here
          

          const { toEntityResponse } = strapi.service("plugin::graphql.format").returnTypes;
          const response = await strapi.services["plugin::upload.adminfile"].remove(args);

          // other logic will also goes here

          // This is not necessary if you want to return something custom
          return toEntityResponse(response);
        },
      },
    },
  }));
};
```